# php array_map callback parameter scope

Tags: php, scope, php-5.3

In the following code the callback function passed to wrap_map can't see the argument in the outer function, why? (see code comment for detail)

```
public static function wrap_implode($ar, $wrap, $delim){
  echo "wrap is $wrap"; //wrap is ok
  $res = array_map(function($val){
     echo "wrap is $wrap"; //wrap is not set here!
     return $wrap. $val . $wrap;
   }, $ar);

   return implode($delim, $res);
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because it is in another scope. If you want to use `$wrap`, try:

```
function($val) use ($wrap){
   //etc
}
```

Of course, your function here doesn't need a callback:

```
return $wrap.implode($wrap.$delim.$wrap,$ar).$wrap;
```